# configure.ac specify folder for all build files

Tags: gnu, autotools, automake

I am new with autotools, but I cant find chapter in autotools doc that coresponds to my question.

Is there command, that I can specify in configure.ac script, that will store all build stuf (config files, Makefiles, etc.) in one folder (for example ./build) ? Or how I should setup autotools to avoid mess in my repo?
My steps:

```
$autoreconf --install
$./configure
$make
```

Any tutorial or article will be very usefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to do anything special in `configure.ac` to enable out-of-tree
builds. You just need to not do anything wrong. A properly autotooled package will build in-tree or out-of-tree.

Say your autotooled package resides in `./foobar` and you have done your autotooling
correctly so that:

```
cd foobar
./configure
make
make distcheck
```

all works successfully. Then equally:

```
mkdir foobar_build
cd foobar_build
../foobar/configure
make
make distcheck
```

will also work just the same, except that all of the artifacts created by the
`configure` script and `make` will be in `./foobar_build` instead of `./foobar`.

You can't get `autoreconf` to generate the files that *it* creates out-of-tree
(the `configure` script and friends) because these are to be included in the 
distribution tarball produced by `make dist` (e.g. `foobar-1.0.tar.gz`). The
end user of an autotooled package should not need to have or understand the autotools:
they should just be able to:

- clone, or download and extract
- configure
- make
- as root, make install

For the same reason the `configure` script and friends *should* be in the
source control repository, at least in the release branch that you
publish for cloning.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, that's really clarified my view.